# find latest comment using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to sync the Facebook comments with my own database, but downloading the full list via Graph API and syncing it on every page view is extremely inefficient.

Is it possible to grab just the most recent comment or nested comment from a URL? That way I could compare entry dates and decide whether a full merge should be done.

Comment: You might try to add [Real-time API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) so that you can update the entry as soon it is created.

Comment: thanks - I think that might be the answer